dynamic spring.config.import file not working with vault sidecar and spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-config
I am trying to use a vault agent sidecar where I am injecting a secret into my kubernetes pod at the location /vault/secrets/.... I then use a spring.config.import property to pull in that file for my application.
I have a @RefreshScope annotated component that is logging the secret information for debugging purposes, which I have compared to the secret information that is mounted to the container. The logged information does not change from initial startup, while the secret file content does.
I am also using a config map with kubernetes which is the reason for needing this dependency.
I am using a spring boot parent on version 2.7.18 along with
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2021.0.8</version>

to manage my spring cloud version
Here is my bootstrap.properties file:
spring.config.activate.on-profile=kubernetes
spring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled=true
spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.enabled=false
spring.cloud.kubernetes.reload.enabled=false
spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.enabled=true
spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.paths=/vault/secrets
spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.name=app

Here is how I am integrating my vault sidecar (with some stuff swapped to hide context):
            vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true" # this deployment will need secrets from Vault
            vault.hashicorp.com/role: namespace-app # auth role to log in to Vault
            vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-azure-app: azure/creds/namespace-app # path to a secret
            vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-azure-app: | # template for the secret in environment file format 
              {{- with secret "azure/creds/namespace-app" -}}
              {{ range $k, $v := .Data }}
              azure.{{ $k }}={{ $v }}
              {{ end }}
              {{- end }}
            vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-containers: "${{APP_NAME}}"
            vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-command-azure-app: |
              curl -s --request POST http://127.0.0.1:8081/actuator/refresh
            vault.hashicorp.com/agent-revoke-on-shutdown: "true"

The config map works and has for a while. The sidecar itself works and injects/updates the credentials in the file when necessary. What isn't working is the spring application itself updating the properties and thus causing issues.
I have tried using the secrets functionality of the kubernetes starter with no additional luck.
Additionally, I have tried running the app locally if I swap out spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-config for spring-cloud-starter and hit my actuator refresh endpoint I can see those credentials refresh both on the /actuator/refresh endpoint and in the application debug logs. However with the integration of the kubernetes starter it stops working. Locally I pulled all properties into my application.properties to reduce spots of failure.

that version is not supported anymore, so you will have to upgrade, to alt least 3.x.x. Then, if you still have the issue you can go to our github project and open a defect, where you will be asked to provide a sample of how to reproduce the issue... When that happens, I can try to help me a lot more. thank you
